# Nashorn JJS: incuding all jars in folder at cpasspath

Tags: jvm, nashorn, jjs

I am using Nashorn's JJS with -classpath to load all the jars in a folder.

I have tried the following :

jjs -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m -cp "C:/orientDB/lib/*" test.js

> "Illegal char <*> at index 16: C:/orientDB/lib/*" is not a recognized
>   option. Use "-h" or "-help" to see a list of all supported options.

jjs -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m -cp C:/orientDB/lib/* test.js

> C:\orientDB\lib\ant-1.8.3.jar:2:7 Missing space after numeric literal 
>   ?3Z@                    META-INF/??  PK

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I verified that "*" in -cp option works with jjs - I used Mac to test it. My jjs version is 1.8.0_112.

```
jjs -cp tmp/*
```

worked for me. in "tmp" directory, I had a single jar and from jjs prompt I can refer to the classes in that jar.

Comment: I only have access to windows for a few days, I will check it on linux soon.  But did not work on my windows for more than one jar in the dir.

Comment: You're right. Even on Mac, it does not seem to work if there are more than one jar files in that directory! A co-worker confirms that "*" in class path + single jar works on Windows/Cygwin - but not with "cmd" shell. If this is a very important feature, please do file an rfe against jjs / OpenJDK. Thanks.

Comment: yes, I think this is an important feature, currently we need to ask clients to use our own script runner app instead of JJS.  It works, but has a hackish feel with the standard JJS not picking up the classpath as expected.  I will open an issue